# Is there a video capture device for IRIX & Sparc video?

Tags: hardware, video

I have a couple of old non-intel machines for porting stuff, and they have a special monitor cable.

I would like to be able to throw away these old CRTs and instead be able to see their video by capturing it into a USB port of a modern machine. Performance is not an issue.

Is there such a thing?

The video connections look something like this:
http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/mxsun_2215_37738309

(capturing pure VGA also interesting)

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a SUN 13W3 connector, you can get [adaptors](http://www.lindy.co.uk/sun-sparc-monitor-adapter-male-to-female/70127.html) to allow you to connect them to a VGA monitor.

Alternatively they are presumably using X11 so you can try something like [XMing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) as a local server for your old machines.

Comment: That assumes that they are in working order. I want to be able to control the boot process too. Some machines have a serial console, but SGI for example is very graphical. I can keep their keyboard (if special), but the CRT is a bit big. Would prefer to not have to lug even a LCD screen in place, which is why I'd prefer a video capture USB device.

Comment: Adaptor and a KVM switch?

Comment: Good suggestions, but I'd prefer something I can bring my laptop to.

Comment: Got an adaptor, so the CRTs are out. Yay.